# Can worklight.properties be used to set mime types in server.xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mime-types

In worklight, I need to add a mime type to server.xml. Can this be done using some configuration such as worklight.properties?

Answer (score 0):

worklight.properties contains properties that relate to Worklight, not to the underlying application server. You should follow standard operations for your application server.

For example, for WebSphere Liberty: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014798730

Comment: I am looking for some way to configure the underlying server via the worklight build process, but maybe we will have to do it ourselves.